# Install 32 bit x86 version of Ubuntu 11.04 on a 64 bit capable Core 2 Duo computer

Tags: ubuntu, 32-bit, multi-boot, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.04 on my Core 2 Duo PC using the 'Ubuntu installer for Windows' so that I can dual-boot to Windows 7 (32bit) or Ubuntu 11.04. I already have the x86 alternative ISO with me. I have placed the ISO file in the same folder as the Ubuntu installer EXE. However, the installer doesn't care about the ISO I placed and downloads the amd64 version of ISO.

How do I make the Ubuntu installer for Windows to download & install 32 bit version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is in the Wubi guide:

[Can I force Wubi to download and install a 32 bit version of Ubuntu?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_download_and_install_a_32_bit_version_of_Ubuntu.3F)

> Yes: either pre-download the appropriate 32 bit ISO manually and place
>   it in the same folder as Wubi.exe or **start Wubi with the "--32bit"
>   argument**.
>
> To modify arguments, right-click Wubi.exe and select "Create
>   Shortcut". Then right-click the shortcut, select Properties, and
>   modify the Target line, for example: "C:\Documents and
>   Settings\\Desktop\wubi.exe" --32bit